# MappingException: No persister for in N-tier application with fluent mapping

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have following project's structure:

[image: project structure]

My models are in **NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity**
and my maps are in **NHibernateTesteWeb.Data.Map**

Here is my Company class:

```
namespace NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity
{
    public class Company
    {
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and here the map class for the Company:

```
namespace NHibernateTesteWeb.Data.Map
{
    public class CompanyMap : ClassMap<Company>
    {
        public CompanyMap()
        {
            Table("Company");
            Id(c => c.Id).GeneratedBy.Native();
            Map(c => c.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

In NHibernateHelper class:

```
...  

static NHibernateHelper()
{            
    _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c=>c.Server(@"(localdb)\Projects")
        .Database("StockAnalyser")
        .TrustedConnection()))                
        .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Company>())
        .Mappings(c => c.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<BDICode>()).BuildSessionFactory();
 }
```

When I run solution, it raises the following exception:

**No persister for: NHibernateTesteWeb.Domain.Entity.Company**
*Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.*

I was getting a same error with xml mapping. Then I change for the Fluent mapping. But the error wasn't solved.

I have hosted my project in github for most easily you help me:
https://github.com/samsg/NHibernateSample

Thank you very much for your useful help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if this is because you've chained the calls to `Mappings()`. Can you try:

```
static NHibernateHelper()
{            
    _sessionFactory = 
        Fluently.Configure()
        // ...
            .Mappings(
                c => 
                    c.FluentMappings
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<Company>()
                        .AddFromAssemblyOf<BDICode>())
            .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

This is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6062220/1162077

Comment: I tried your solution. Unfortunately It didn't work. Some other tip? Thanks.